# Mongodb event listener/triggers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a node.js application with mongodb as my datastore. I have a ttl collection. I need to listen for document delete events and call a node.js function.

I understand from the old SO threads oplog is one way to monitor and trigger. But is there any new functionality that can accomplish this? I hate oplog way its additional resource consuming.

Thanks!